# SAP Cloud sdk android - read offline data

Tags: android, sap-cloud-sdk

I have been using SAP Cloud SDK for Android to generate a native application.
It uses an ODATA Service and has offline functionalities.
Everything works fine... I have 5 Entities and wizard has created CRUD forms for them, and synchronization works fine too.

The big question is, how can I in my custom code read a list of entities?
for example, I have an entity Products, how can I populate a list of Products from data on my phone?

I have been following

https://help.sap.com/doc/c2d571df73104f72b9f1b73e06c5609a/Latest/en-US/docs/sample_code/odata/Query.html

but I don't know what is `demoService` in my case?

Answer (score 1):

In the generated offline mobile app, the 'service' package has the sample code on how to sync the offline data with server. 'repository' and 'viewmodel' packages have the code related to reading data from the offline database. And please see 'ESPMContainer' in the 'generated' folder, it should be the 'demoService' as in the OData document.